# How to make post request with certyficate auth

Tags: java, okhttp

I need a post request to the server where I will authorize with a certificate. I have the certificate in file.p12 secured by a password. I think I have checked all the solutions on this site and unfortunately none of them work.

I wanted to use OkHttp, but all solutions use libraries that have already been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://tls.p12");
ks.load(fis, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
URL url = new URL("https://.....");

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
}
X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory(), trustManager)
        .build();
```